# Pattern Matching on GADTs

Tags: haskell, typeclass, gadt

I've created a GADT for expressions. When I pattern match on constructors that have constraints, the typechecker is unable to deduce constraints on the type variables used in the constructor's constraints. I think the code and error message are more elucidating.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
import Data.Word

data Expr a where
  Value :: a -> Expr a
  Cast :: (Castable a b) => Expr a -> Expr b

class Castable a b where
  cast :: a -> b

instance Castable Word64 Word32 where
  cast = fromIntegral

instance (Show a) => Show (Expr a) where
  show (Cast e) = "Cast " ++ show e -- ERROR
```

The error I get:

```
gadt.hs:16:30:
    Could not deduce (Show a1) arising from a use of `show'
    from the context (Show a)
      bound by the instance declaration at gadt.hs:15:10-34
    or from (Castable a1 a)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 Cast :: forall b a. Castable a b => Expr a -> Expr b,
               in an equation for `show'
      at gadt.hs:16:9-14
    Possible fix:
      add (Show a1) to the context of
        the data constructor `Cast'
        or the instance declaration
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `show e'
    In the expression: "Cast " ++ show e
    In an equation for `show': show (Cast e) = "Cast " ++ show e
```

---

Edit: If I comment out the `Show (Expr a)` instance and add the following code, it works fine:

```
eval :: Expr a -> a
eval (Value a) = a
eval (Cast e) = cast $ eval e

main = do
  let bigvalue = maxBound `div` 2 + 5 :: Word64
      e = Cast (Value bigvalue) :: Expr Word32
      v = eval e
  putStrLn "typechecks."
  print (bigvalue, v)
```

I would want the show instance to basically print something like `Cast (Value bigvalue)`.

Comment: It can't deduce that b is an instance of Show I guess, this compiles: http://ideone.com/BWtyIR and so does this http://ideone.com/6KiB3W

Comment: What behavior are you expecting? The type in the `Cast` value is existential, so you don't know anything about, e.g. how to show it. Your current GADT is essentially equivalent to something like `data Expr a = Value a | Cast (Expr a)`. You could add a `Show` constraint but I suspect that's a case of treating the symptom, and that what you should really do is take a step back and think about what you're trying to do in the first place.

Comment: I agree with shachaf, I'm not sure what you actually want here.

Comment: @Wes: Your code compiles but you changed the type of the `Cast` constructor.

Comment: @nitromaster101 the problem is that you're confusing `Expr a` with `Expr b` in the instance declaration for `Castable`. I'm not sure exactly which behaviour you want although I doubt you want the first version I posted. Why do you want to show the result of the cast anyway?

Comment: @shachaf: I don't understand why this GADT is equivalent to the standard data constructor (the important difference is that in the GADT, `Cast` takes one type and converts to another). I understand that there might be a problem printing an arbitrary `Expr a` because I don't know the type `b` which satisfies `Castable`, but once I'm dealing with a specific instance (like `e` in main), I don't know why it shouldn't be able to work.

Comment: @nitromaster101 it may be true that you've used it in such a way that the result is an instance of `Show` but the compiler can't prove that it will *always* be the case that you've called it with something you can show.

Comment: I think a full explanation of GADT behavior is outside the scope of this comment field. Note that your `Cast` declaration is also equivalent to e.g. `Cast :: Castable a b => Expr b -> Expr a` -- GADT variables aren't scoped. I don't know what your "real question" -- what you're actually trying to do -- is, but I suspect it deserves its own SO question (to which a GADT might well be the answer).

Comment: @Wes Showing the expression isn't that important; ultimately I'm going to evaluate it, but I thought it should be possible. What do you mean by confusing `Expr a` with `Expr b`? I just saw your second suggestion: that's interesting, although I want to be able to cast between many instances. I think that your code wouldn't allow `Cast (Cast (Value (3 :: Word64)) :: Expr Word32) :: Expr Word16`.

Comment: OK, thanks so much for your comments. Along with @Ben's answer, they really helped. Ultimately, the real question was how to create an expression type that allowed for type-aware casting. I didn't fully grok that by creating this GADT I was losing `b`'s type (except for the `Castable` constraint). For future reference, to fix this particular `Show` problem, I can just add a `Show b` constraint in `Cast`.

Comment: To avoid confusion is GADTs it's best to keep the result types of the constructors as consistent as possible.  In this case `Cast :: (Castable b a) => Expr b -> Expr a` would probably have been enough for you to understand what the problem was.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Cast :: (Castable a b) => Expr a -> Expr b
```

So here:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Expr a) where
  show (Cast e) = "Cast " ++ show e -- ERROR
```

`Cast e` is of type `Expr a`. We have a `Show a` constraint, and by this very instance that implies `Show (Expr a)`, so we can call `show` on things of type `Expr a`.

But `e` is **not** of type `Expr a`. `Cast` takes an argument of *any* type `Expr a1` and gives you an `Expr a` (renaming the type variables to stay consistent with what we're talking about in the instance), so `e` is of type `Expr a1`. We *don't* have a `Show` constraint for the type `a1`, and we require `Show a1` to imply `Show (Expr a1)`, so there's no way to `show e`.

And there's no way to add such a constraint in the `Show` instance, because the type `a1` doesn't appear in the type of `Cast e`. That seems to be the whole point of using a GADT here; you've *deliberately* thrown away all information about the type of the thing that `Cast` was applied to (other than the fact that `Castable a1 a` holds), and declared the result to simply be `Expr a`.